# set coordinates on BitMap image in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a image of a graph in my WPF project, when i click on the image i get the coordinates of the click.
I want to change where coordinates (0,0) appears.

From the blue circle to the red circle - see image

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Huc.png)

```
            System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(image);
            double pixelWidth = image.Source.Width;
            double pixelHeight = image.Source.Height;
            double x = pixelWidth * p.X / image.ActualWidth;
            double y = pixelHeight * p.Y / image.ActualHeight;

            xgrid.Text = x.ToString();
            ygrid.Text = y.ToString();
```

How is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to know the pixel offset of the graph's 0,0  origin from the bottom left of the image.  Without that information, you're out of luck.  And since Windows Y coordinates increase as you go downwards and you want your Y coordinates to increase as you go upwards, you would have to do the math to adjust for that.  If there is anyway for you to show this graph not as an image but as a control that draws its contents, things will probably be a lot easier.

Comment: Im new to WPF, so if you could be more specific about what to do i would be grateful :)

Comment: How is the image in your picture generated in the first place?  Where do you get it?  Is it something you just load from disk?  Is there some graphing software somewhere that converts what it draws to an image?

Comment: The img just comes from my cpu and i convert it to BitmapImage in VS.

Comment: First, your code will not report 0,0 where you circled blue because in WPF, Y coordinates increase as you go down the screen in all windows controls.  That's not 0,0, it's something like 0, 200.  or 0, 150. 
 You would have to do something like what Mark Feldman suggests just to get the Y orientation right.  And then you need to know the pixel difference between the blue-circled point and the red-circled point.  If all you have is an image, *there is no way to do that*.   So either you need to know that pixel offset or you need access to the vector data that was used to create the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a point from one control's client space to another with `UIElement.TranslatePoint`:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // assuming "this" is the parent
    var parentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    Point childPoint = this.TranslatePoint(parentPoint, theChild);
}
```

Of course, if your chart is a child control then you can just pass that into GetPosition() instead, while keeping the `MouseDown` handler in the parent:

```
var childPoint = e.GetPosition(theChild);
```

Either way, if you want the vertical axis reversed then adjust the Y value accordingly:

```
childPoint.Y = theChild.ActualHeight - childPoint.Y - 1;
```